# Sort multidimensional array based upon first integer in each sub array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$final = array(array([0] => 123, [1] => 3, [2] => "true"),
               array([0] => 9, [1] => 4, [3] => "false"),
               array([0] => 541, [1] => 1, [3] => "false"));
```

I tried using php's sort function so that the $final array will be sorted from lowest to highest based upon the $final[$i][0] value, but it doesn't seem to work. This is just a quick example for the sake of in simplicity. In the real problem that I'm working with, the arrays that are inside of the $final array range from having as little as 3 elements to as many as 7. Don't know if that has any effect on the problem or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what PHP's [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function is for:

```
usort($final, function ($a, $b)
{    
    return $a[0] < $b[0] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/omXxkR